# Ubuntu 16.04 WiFi not working

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I have tried almost everything to make my WiFi work. It just gets automatically disconnected and never gets connected unless restarted.
Even `sudo service network-manager restart` doesn't work.
Also my secure boot is disabled and in additional drivers, I can only see one *Unknown Driver*.
Here's what I get when I enter `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: ec:8e:b5:fb:16:23
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:d6000000-d6000fff memory:d6100000-d6103fff
*-generic
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Illegal Vendor ID
       vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:13:00.0
       logical name: wlp19s0
       version: ff
       serial: 54:8c:a0:99:3c:c5
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.10.0-36-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d3000000-d3003fff
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20u1
       serial: b6:c8:24:47:35:e0
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.93 link=yes multicast=yes
```

code: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
  13:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Kernel modules: rtl8723be
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `dkms status`:

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.10.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Why do I get illegal vendor id? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Added..

Comment: The IDs look correct. Most likely you installed some 3rd party driver. Please add output of `dkms status`. But the module is in use. This means that it has been built.

Comment: There is no 3rd party driver installed. In additional drivers, only one driver is listed named Unknown. @Pilot6 Question updated.

Comment: `bcmwl` is a 3rd party driver and it is installed.  It is a Broadcom proprietary driver. Anyway it is useless. You can remove it by `sudo dkms remove bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom --all`.

Comment: Okay removed, but everything is still the same! It also keeps showing "Device not ready" @pilot6

Comment: This looks like a hardware issue.

Comment: I am having windowns 10 in dual boot. And WiFi is working perfectly fine in it. So, i guess it's not a hardware issue.

Comment: Then "upgrading from 15.04 to 16.04" went wrong. It is not supported to upgrade this way. Boot from 16.04.3 LiveUSB and check if Wi-Fi works.

Comment: Actually i didn't upgrade from 15.04 to 16.04. Did a fresh installation through live usb. My internet works after every restart but gets disconnected automatically after a few minutes and doesn't get connected until restarted!

Comment: Did you read the question title? It's unclear what you did then.

Comment: Okay changed. That's the actual problem.

Comment: The problem is unclear. The device should work.

Comment: Anything that i can do? What about that "Illegal Vendor Id"?

Comment: Something is wrong with your installation. If you do a fresh install, all should work.